# Law of Quadratic Reciprocity for primes that are congruent 3 or 1 modulo 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I have a question regarding some claims I read about the Law of Quadratic Reciprocity that I can't fully understand. The law itself is written as follows:

For all odd numbers $P,Q \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\gcd(Q,P) = 1$ we have:
$\left(\frac{Q}{P}\right) = (-1)^{(P-1)(Q-1)/4}\left(\frac{P}{Q}\right)$

The claims that I read are that from here it is implied that for an odd prime $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p}$ if $p \equiv 3\bmod\ 4$, either $a$ or $-a$ is a quadratic residue, while if $p \equiv 1\bmod 4$ both $a$ and $-a$ are either quadratic residues, or quadratic nonresidues.

Now I don't have much experience when it comes to this area of math, so these claims are not that obvious to me just by looking at the law of quadratic reciprocity, so I wanted to ask kindly if someone can perhaps shed some light onto why is this the case?

Comment: What other facts about quadratic residues or non-residues do you know?

Comment: I know that Jacobi symbol should be 1 in order for number to be a residue. I am also given 5 supplements in order to help calculating Jacobi symbol. They are as follow: 

SUPLEMENT 1: if $a \equiv b\ mod\ Q$ then $\left(\frac{a}{Q}\right) = \left(\frac{b}{Q}\right)$

SUPLEMENT 2: $\left(\frac{1}{Q}\right) = 1$

SUPLEMENT 3: $\left(\frac{-1}{Q}\right) = (-1)^{(Q-1)/2}$

SUPLEMENT 4: $\left(\frac{ab}{Q}\right) =  \left(\frac{a}{Q}\right)  \cdot  \left(\frac{b}{Q}\right) $

SUPLEMENT 5: $\left(\frac{2}{Q}\right) = (-1)^{(Q^{2}-1)/8}$

Comment: This video explains it better than I can..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X63MWZIN3gM

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Given that you know the supplemental rules, you can compute
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{-a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{a}{p}\right).
\end{equation*}
in each of the cases you are interested in.